# Displaying and adding column to a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe called **date** as follows, but I am not able to call that dataframe by typing **date** in further cells. I need to call that dataframe as a table and add new column to it.

Right now, this is what I have:

```py
date = data.groupby(pd.to_datetime(data['Completion Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.month)['Learning    Hours'].sum()
date.index = pd.to_datetime(date.index, format='%m').month_name().str[:3]
date.rename_axis('Month').reset_index(name='Learning hours')
```

O/P:

```
Month   Learning hours

Jan     349.5

Feb     417.0
```

I need to add a new column to this table called **Required**, with values 430 in all rows as shown in the below:

needed O/P:

```
Month   Learning hours  Required

Jan     349.5           430

Feb     417.0           430
```

Comment: Added codeblocks to make output and code more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is necessary assign output back to `date` variable and then create new colum:

```
date = data.groupby(pd.to_datetime(data['Completion Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.month)['Learning Hours'].sum() 
date.index = pd.to_datetime(date.index, format='%m').month_name().str[:3] 
date = date.rename_axis('Month').reset_index(name='Learning hours')
date['Required'] = 430
```

You can simplify solution if possible lowercases first 3 letters of months names:

```
months = (pd.to_datetime(data['Completion Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
            .dt.strftime('%b')
            .rename('Month'))
date = (data.groupby(months, sort=False)['Learning Hours']
            .sum()
            .reset_index(name='Learning hours'))
date['Required'] = 430
```

Or:

```
months = (pd.to_datetime(data['Completion Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
            .dt.strftime('%b')
            .rename('Month'))
date = (data.groupby(months, sort=False)['Learning Hours']
            .sum()
            .reset_index(name='Learning hours')
            .assign(Required = 430))
```

Comment: But how to print Jan, Feb in that order. Your code is printing Feb first.

Comment: @VishvamNaik - How working `data.groupby(months, sort=False)` ?

Comment: It is working for all the months except Mar, Apr. I don't know what's the issue there. @jezrael

Comment: @VPN If data are not confidental is possible share them?